# Differentiating a stochastic integral

Tags: calculus, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, wiener-measure

How do i differentiate the following stochatic integral?

$$\frac {d}{dW_t} \int_{0}^t \frac{1}{1-u}  dW_u$$

My guess is

$$\frac {d}{dW_t} \int_{0}^t \frac{1}{1-u}  dW_u = \left.\frac {1}{1-u} \right\vert_{u=0}^{u=t}=\frac {1}{1-t} - 1$$

but ive seen it solved without the lower limit and just be

$$\frac {d}{dW_t} \int_{0}^t \frac{1}{1-u}  dW_u = \frac {1} {1-t}$$

Answer (score 1):

Well if you do the standard FTC you would just get the upper limit, so this makes intuitive sense.

Comment: is there an intuitive formula i can use? when googling FTC it looks like its deriving with respect to the upper limit. which is similar to leibniz.
Also, whats the intuition behind only using the upper limit

Comment: It is the one with dependence on $t$